# How to Join Local Windows Machine to AWS Active Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, active-directory, amazon-vpc

Hi my goal is to create Active Directory in AWS.  I used simple AD and used 2 public and 2 private subnets within the same VPC with the private ones being for the domain controllers.  I created an EC2 instance within the same VPC with Windows Server so that I can manage the AD.  My EC2 instance joins the domain with no problem.  My problem however is I cannot get my local machines on my network to join the AD, as the DC's, are of course private IP's and I cant change the DNS on my machine to these IP's unless on the same network.

Im guessing I need a VPN to join my local network to the Network in the AWS cloud.

Is there a way to achieve having AD in AWS without a VPN such as using an elastic IP with NAT to communicate to the DC's?  Or maybe even promoting my EC2 instance to a DC then connecting the local machines DNS to the EC2 instances elastic IP?

Any help is much appreciated and let me know if I am missing any information or not explaining the goal clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question mentions Simple AD. My comments will be for Active Directory in AWS.

Setting up Active Directory in AWS and on-premises is not as easy as I would like it to be. This topic can fill a small book or as Amazon does it, multiple hour long videos. Watch a few while thinking up your solution.

1) Simple AD is not real Active Directory. It is Samba 4, which is very good, but is an Active Directory clone.

2) Do not, and I repeat do not, think about putting Active Directory on a public IP address to serve your on-premises users. The number of ports that you need to open and the risk is just not worth it.

3) Most, if not all, real solutions for configuring Active Directory on-premises and in AWS involve VPNs. Either Direct Connect (DX), hardware routers (Cisco) or site to site VPNs built from OpenSwan or Windows Server.

Note: OpenSwan is very easy to setup, so this is the route I would recommend if cost is a factor. Otherwise look at Cisco ASA type routers (lots of vendors here) for your office and setup a VPN with IPSEC. If cost is not a factor, absolutely go with Direct Connect (DX).

Note: I also use OpenVPN to connect to AD in AWS from home. This setup routes my workstation to a VPC in AWS and is so easy to setup and use. You could start with this to get comfortable with networking to a VPC. There are preconfigured OpenVPN setups in AWS marketplace that are free (user limited).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer.  I have seen already 4, 1 hour videos on this as well as read the white paper multiple times.  What you are saying makes complete sense.  Maybe Azure has a better way of handling this but in the end I think it will be the same situation.

Comment: Samba is not an Active Directory clone, It started as an open SMB implementation and with version 4 can emulate a **very limited** (lacking hundreds of features) Microsoft Domain Controller, allowing users to authenticate using Kerberos on its LDAP instead of relying on a pre-existent AD. Btw LDAP, which is the closest thing to ADDS, is also not an AD clone, since AD is based on LDAP.

Comment: @nnsense - I am not sure what point you are trying to make about Samba and Simple AD. Your comments are correct about Samba but do not apply to my answer in this context. If you have a better answer, please post an answer.

Comment: A comment to a given answer goes into the answer's comment area. This is why we have a comment area, to discuss and improve the other's answers. Alternatively I could directly edit your answer and remove the wrong statement, up to you.

Comment: Again what point are you trying to make? Where in my answer did I say that Samba is an Active Directory clone? I said that Simple AD is an Active Directory clone. Once again, if you have good/better information, post an answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to make any point, you've written that Simple AD, (which is Samba4), is an AD clone and I don't think that's completely right, and I added my comment to clarify that exactly like everyone else is doing here on stack, sorry if this hurt your feelings.

Comment: so the only way to connect local machine to the AWS managed AD is via AWS VPN? If yes i have a query does the VPN is required only to connect the local pc to domain after which the VPN is not required? or on every login to the PC the VPN will connect automatically